# How can i add reference of all Javascript files in one?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a situation here. i have started angularjs project from the scratch. for every js file i am adding to my project it require its reference in index.html. which i want to avoid . can anyone please suggest me the best possible and easy implemented way to resolve it.

i am looking for kind of 2 options:(but dnt know how to do it)

1) single file which contain all js files and then that single file can refers in index.html

2) or it should be somehow added automatically when browser required it?

obviously there might be others options as well other then just mentioned above.
any suggestion will be helpful
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're looking for [gulp](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp) with [this plugin](https://github.com/klei/gulp-inject#basic-usage).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Alexander said, if you choose [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com), you can use a [concat plugin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat) to merge a list of selected files into a single destination:

after you load the select plugin in your gruntfile.js

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
```

define a task in grunt configuration:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  concat: {
    options: {
      separator: ';',
    },
    dist: {
      // your source file list
      src: ['src/js/*.js'], 
      //your destination file
      dest: 'dist/app.js',
    },
  },
});
```

then register this task to a list:

```
grunt.registerTask('compile', ['concat']);
```

this would be run by typing "grunt compile" on the command line

so you only have to include the dist/app.js file in your index.

There are many plugins available in grunt, i.e. you can inculde your app.js file dynamically using the [grunt-include-source](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-include-source) plugin, or minimize the js files using [grunt-contrib-uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify).

More information on the gruntfile are available [here](http://gruntjs.com/sample-gruntfile)

You can achieve the result as requested in the second point instead, i think you could use solutions like:

- [WebPack](https://webpack.github.io/)
- [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)

**UPDATE**:

I couldn't find a concat end to end tutorial, I'm sorry.

For a generic Grunt tutorial you can read [this](http://adrianmejia.com/blog/2014/10/07/grunt-js-tutorial-from-beginner-to-ninja/)

Otherwise you can follow the [getting started](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started) page from the official Grunt site for installation, configuration and have a general overview.

When they talk about plugins please refer to the README of the [grunt-contrib-concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat) plugin linked and explained above.

Those pages could give you all the skills needed.

Finally, customize the concat configuration in Gruntfile.js by putting in `dist.src` all files to be merged into the file set as `dist.dest` and only include the latter in your html.

Once the set-up is complete, execute your task by typing `grunt compile` on the command line in your project folder, and the merged file will be produced.

Comment: Thanks Jenjis,can you please suggest any url which i can follow to have end to end implementation for my problem. as code you ave mention above is new for me so need slight background and flow how i can implement it on my project.

Comment: Thanks a lot.i am able to do it. and links you have provided solved my concept as well. i still have to do bit and bites for fixing it into my environment as i am running my application through VS2013 where just f5 should load all javascripts files rather then through grunt file. but i thing i can do it in postbuild batch file. :)

Answer (score 1):

As it has been already mentioned in comments by [ShanShan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5388620/shanshan), [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com) (or [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/)) is what you're looking for.

So, you set up a watch task, and after js file is modified, you concatenate all these files / compress them / whatever.

I bet this topic has been already discussed a lot.

Please consider the basic app generated with [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) and [Yeoman angular generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular).

Best regards, Alexander